# blenderのpythonから出力されるログを見たい

Tags: python, macos, blender

#### 前提・実現したいこと

**環境**
Blender2.8
Python 3.7.3
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

blenderのpythonから出力されるログを見たい

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

Blender2.8でpythonを使ってメッシュを動かしたく、
この動画 https://youtu.be/O7nNO3FLkLU を元にやろうとしていました。
インストールは一通り済ませ、配布されてるコードやプロジェクトをDLしたのですが、実行時に以下のメッセージが表示され実行が出来ません。

```
bpy.ops.text.run_script()
Pythonスクリプトが失敗。システムコンソールのメッセージをチェックしてください。
```

その際、詳細なエラーの内容やprintデバッグの結果が出力されず、どこを直せばいいのかわからない状態です。

#### 試したこと

検索して出てきたサイトによると、ターミナルから起動すればターミナルへログが出力されると聞いたのですが、その通り `open blender.app` で起動しても出力されませんでした。

何のエラーが出ているかやprintした結果などを見れるようにする方法を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: これらのどれかでしょうか。[How to open system console to get output from Blender on Mac OS 10?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/102860), [ターミナルからBlenderを起動](https://blenderapproach.wordpress.com/), [ログメッセージを表示する](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/guide/console/cnsl1012/1.0/mac/10.13)

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/219660

Answer (score 1):

こちらのリンクを見て、ターミナルからblenderのエラーが表示されるようになりました。

[Mac でBlenderのPrint結果を表示する](http://dekapoppo.blogspot.com/2017/12/mac-blenderprint.html)